# Maximum pixel value in array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to get the max (and min) pixel value in an array.

Imagine I have the next numpy array:

```
image = np.array([
          [150, 160, 200],
          [80, 120, 90],
          [220, 200, 180]
        ])
```

I want to get that the maximum pixel value is the `[220, 200, 180]` value, because the sum of all BGR channels is greater than the others.

I know that I can use `np.max(image, axis=0)` to get `[220, 200, 200]`, but that's not what I am looking for.

Any idea on how to do that? I could iterate over all the numpy array, sum the values and get the index of the greater, but there must be a better way to perform this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you want to get the index of the max sum?

```
image[np.argmax(image.sum(1))]
```

output: `array([220, 200, 180])`